# NullPointerException when using CheckBox in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, checkbox

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setChecked(boolean)' on a null object reference

This is the error I cannot figure out why it happens.

Here is my **java class**:

```
public class PopUpInfoActivity extends Activity {
static final String PREFS = "preference_file";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);

    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.dontshow_checkbox);
    chk.setChecked(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("value", false));

    chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //store isChecked to Preferences
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS,0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("isChecked", false);

            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PopUpInfoActivity.this).edit().putBoolean("value", isChecked).apply();
        }
    });
}
}
```

In which I imported `android.widget.CheckBox`

and this is my **xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/legenda" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/dontshow_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dont_show"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I would really appreciate if you could help me fix this error!

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.xmllayout);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the correct `id` but you're missing one very important line - `setContentView`. That line binds the xml with the Activity's view and it's the view that's being used for `findViewById`. Add this line to your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.name_of_the_xml);
```

And then the rest of your code. Be sure to provide a correct xml name.

Comment: thank you for the answer! what a silly mistake!! can't believe I couldn't see that!

Comment: You're welcome. Ah, I know, sometimes it takes someone else to see what you missed. Happens to me often :D